# Django REST Framework How to Efficiently Filter Calculate Model property

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, saas

I have a model property of `is_expired` that simply returns `True` or `False` by comparing the current time with another field called `Saas_expire_date`.

```
 @ property
    def is_expired(self):
        current_time = timezone.now()
        return current_time > self.saas_expire_date
```

How do i efficiently filter this.. I fear That using `For` loops will drastically affect response time especial if there is alot of data

```
class StorePublicAPI(APIView):
    """
    Store API for client side
    """

    def get(self, request):
        """
        `Get Stores`
        """
        raw_stores = Store.objects.filter(
            is_approved=True, is_active=True)
        stores = []
        for store in raw_stores:
            if not store.is_expired:
                stores.append(store)

        serializer = StorePublicSerializer(stores, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

or can you help me if finding a more effective way of calculating whether a user has paid or not? when the `Saas_expire_date` field reaches the current date time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually doing a time filter for the `saas_expiry_date` field in your `is_expired` property. Why not do it also in filter?

```
class StorePublicAPI(APIView):
    """
    Store API for client side
    """

    def get(self, request):
        """
        `Get Stores`
        """
        current_time = timezone.now()
        queryset = Store.objects.filter(
            is_approved= True,
            is_active=True,
            saas_expire_date__lt=current_time,
        )

        serializer = StorePublicSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: WOW!.. its amazing how there is a very simple solution to this! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what your saas_expire_date looks like, but assuming it's a DateField or DateTimeField, you can filter your `Store` model using [an `lte` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#lte) like this:

```
class StorePublicAPI(APIView):
    """
    Store API for client side
    """

    def get(self, request):
        """
        `Get Stores`
        """
        stores = Store.objects.filter(
            saas_expire_date__lte=timezone.now(),
            is_approved=True,
            is_active=True)

        serializer = StorePublicSerializer(stores, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Make sure you have your timezone configuration implemented correctly, otherwise you might run into issues with objects being returned off by a few hours. Check the docs for timezones [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/)